# Can multiple Cobol subroutines be in the same module

Tags: cobol

In java, I can create a utility type class that has many helper type methods.  Cobol is a language good for many things, but inability to pass parms to an internal paragraph is not one of them.  I've started using some subroutines in separate modules and calling them.  This leads to 2 questions:

1. Anyone know the relative performance of an internal paragraph call vs an "external" subroutine call?  I do include the subroutine module in my linkage editor control card.
2. Is there an ability to use one module to include mutliple subroutines?  Looks like the linkage section precludes this ... but wondering if there is a way to create a Cobol module analog to a helper class (full of helper methods).

Thanks,

Comment: It all depends on your compiler, which is ...?

Answer (score 5):

For question 1, it depends on the implementation and compiler options.

For question 2, with COBOL 85, multiple programs may be compiled from the same source. For example:

```
    program-id. prog-1.
    ...
    end program prog-1.
    program-id. prog-2.
    ...
    end program prog-2.
    etc.
```

Each program is, as if, it were compiled separately. Any common data or files shared by these programs may be made available to each by using the `EXTERNAL` clause.

Programs may also be nested. For example,

```
    program-id. multi-nested.
        ...
    program-id. prog-1.
        ....
    end program prog-1.
    program-id. prog-2.
        ....
    end program prog-2.
    end program multi-nested.
```

Any common data or files shared by these programs may be made available to each by using the `GLOBAL` clause.

Some implementations allow an `ENTRY` statement. For example,

```
    program-id. multi-entry.
        ...
    linkage section.
        ...
    procedure division [ using ... ].
        ...
        entry "prog-1" using ...
        ...
        entry "prog-2" using ...
        ...
    end program multi-entry.
```

In this example, the `LINKAGE SECTION` contains all parameters, even though each entry point may use only some of them.

The ways in which these may be used will depend a great deal on site standards.